# getResource of a web service in Spring Filter

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, restful-url

In Spring Filter doFilter(), it is easy to check the existence of the JSP file by

```
request.getServletContext().getResource("/test/index.jsp"));
```

If the specified JSP exists, it will return the URL. If not, it will return null.

How can I check the existence of a web service? Let say I declare a service in my controller as:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/getForm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

When I try the following code in `doFilter()`, I get null:

```
request.getServletContext().getResource("/test/getForm"));
```

Is there any way to check the existence of `/test/getForm` ?